# How can I stop github to redirect all project pages to my domain?

Tags: github

I setup a custom domain for [my personal page](http://zation.github.com), but it makes all my other project pages been redirected to it, for example: http://zation.github.com/session/css/box_model/.

So is there any way to stop github to redirect all the other project pages to my domain?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not possible to do that. If you set-up a custom domain for your personal GitHub repo - then all your project pages will be under that domain. See this FAQ page for GitHub pages (under Project pages): https://help.github.com/articles/user-organization-and-project-pages

> A custom domain on user/org pages will apply the same domain redirect
>   to all project pages hosted under that account, unless the project
>   pages use their own custom domain.

Comment: Is there a security / technological reason for not allowing us to not redirect?

Comment: This is unfortunate. Not every project page should need a custom domain.